# browser auto fill issue with input focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, autofill

I have a login form for which browser has saved the user login detail. So when I open this page in the browser it shows me like this
[image]

but when I click on the page or press any button

[image]

this is the expected default behaviour.

I have tried

```
document.body.focus()
```

`onload` but this is not working.

then I set focus on one of the input(on name) but then what about other field? what is the best solution for this?

I know this fancy styling is not good but is there workaround for this?

Comment: I think that one is the label. You can simply set your label to the top when field is touched

Comment: Best way to avoid, is to not implement such “fancy” styling - that only the designer appreciates, but users often rather struggle with - in the first place. https://medium.com/simple-human/floating-labels-are-a-bad-idea-82edb64220f6

Comment: that is the label this works when field is touched but when the page loads autofill fills the username and password and there is no focus so the it behaves as the first screenshot

Comment: @CBroe, I understand but is there any solution for this?

Comment: If you did actually understand and agree, why would you still be asking for a “solution” to it then? :-) https://www.google.com/search?q=browser%20autofill%20and%20floating%20labels shows that other people have already been dealing with this issue, so maybe you can take some inspiration from their solutions (if they actually found any.)

Comment: what if your client not agree with this :( ?

Comment: Please add a link to the source code or paste it here.

Comment: thanks for the compliment and being so judgemental!! kudos

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact issue using React and Styled Components. To resolve the issue I used the following css inside my styled component (which was a `<label>`):

`input:-webkit-autofill + &`

This works by checking for an autofill in the input and applying our desired styling if true.

Note: You may need to replace `&` with `input`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **active** class to the elements in the Login form:

For example:

`<input id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" class="active">`

or added the code snippet below to the css:

```
input:-webkit-autofill { +label { @extend .active; } } }`
```

Let me know if this worked,
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain this?

Comment: Did it worked out ? Else please check out all the possible solution here: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2249#issuecomment-306232296

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.login-form{

  width: 50%;
  }

form div{
padding: 10px;
}

form div label, form div .fa{
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<form class="login-form text-center">
    <h4>Sign in</h4>

 
    <div class="md-form">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
          <label for="materialFormLoginEmailEx">Your email</label><br>
        <input type="email" id="materialFormLoginEmailEx" class="form-control" placeholder="Admin">
      
    </div>

  
    <div class="md-form">
        <i class="fa fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
        <label for="materialFormLoginPasswordEx">Your password</label><br>
        <input type="password" id="materialFormLoginPasswordEx" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        
    </div>

    <div class="login-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).on('load', function (){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('input:-webkit-autofill').each(function (){
            $(this).parent().addClass('focused');
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.form-group.focused .floating-label {
    color: #7b7f82;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: 14px;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group floating-group">
<label class="floating-label">tel</label>
<input type="text" name="telefon" id="telefon">
</div>
```